# Qual a função equivalente a window.location.href de JavaScript em PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Eu pretendo redirecionar o visitante para outra página então queria o equivalente a `window.location.href` em  [php](/questions/tagged/php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use a função [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).**

```
header("Location: http://www.linkDoSite.com/");
exit();
```

Segundo a documentação da função, ela deve ser executada antes que qualquer saída seja enviada. Isso inclui qualquer HTML, texto puro, linhas em branco, espaços ou saídas do próprio PHP.